# Jquery Issue: Why does my alert get triggered multiple times?

Tags: jquery

The code below takes a div and moves it on click. The return button the moves the div back to where it was before. The second alert gets triggered multiples times on occasion. Can someone explain why?

```
<html>
        <head>
            <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
            <style>

            .profile {

                width: 250px;
                height: 250px;
                margin-top: 250px;
                margin-left: 250px;
                border: solid black 1px;
            }

        </style>

        </head>
        <body>
        <script>

            $(document).ready(function(){

                $('.profile').click(function(){

                                    // store current position
                    var activeProfile = $(this);
                    var profilePosition = activeProfile.offset();
                    var initialLeft = profilePosition.left;
                    var initialTop = profilePosition.top;


                    alert(initialLeft);

                    $(this).css({'position' : 'absolute', 'top' : 0, 'left' : 0, 'margin': 0});

                            // return to original start position
                        $('#close').click(function(e) {
                        alert('sometimes i get triggered multiple times!');
                        activeProfile.css({'left' : initialLeft, 'top' : initialTop});
                        e.stopPropagation();


                     });    

                });

            })

        </script>

            <div class="profile">
                <button id="close">Return</button>
            </div>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the culprit is that every time you click the .profile class it associates a event to #close .. So if you click twice it binds two times.. So you need to unbind and associate again to see the alert only once..

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    $('.profile').on('click', function () {

        // store current position
        var activeProfile = $(this);
        var profilePosition = activeProfile.offset();
        var initialLeft = profilePosition.left;
        var initialTop = profilePosition.top;


        alert(initialLeft);

        $(this).css({
            'position': 'absolute',
            'top': 0,
            'left': 0,
            'margin': 0
        });

        // return to original start position
        $('#close').unbind().on('click', function (e) {
            alert('sometimes i get triggered multiple times!');
            activeProfile.css({
                'left': initialLeft,
                'top': initialTop
            });
            e.stopPropagation();


        });

    });

})
```

This is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/k2nj4/) for old code

This is the [UPDATE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/k2nj4/1/) with unbind event associated with it..

Comment: oops .. sorry .. Looks like this is a problem with event Bubbling

Comment: Yep this fixes the issue. Thanks for comprehensive reply!

Answer (score 2):

Every time `.profile` is clicked, you add an additional click handler to `#close`.  Then, once `#close` is clicked, all of those handlers will fire.  If you click `.profile` 3 times, there are three click handlers on `#close` and all three fire.

Comment: Ahhh. Is there a way of getting around this? I need the closure to retain the position. Unbind the handler at the end perhaps?

Comment: You need to unbind the event and again add it.. Check my post above .. i have rewritten the code and posted a fiddle..

Answer (score 0):

1.There might be multiple `.profile` elements on your page and they might be nested within each other?

```
--profile

----profile (so a click here would bubble up and trigger two handlers)
```

2.The code for binding is somehow getting called twice? (Not visible in question, but just guessing since it's quite possible)

Comment: Uhm, even if there are several elements, so what?

Comment: For every element that event is triggered right.. So you see multiple alerts

Comment: @zerkms: So obviously the handler is bound multiple times. Once each for each matching element.

Comment: @Robin Maben: how amount of `.profile` is related to amount of bounds to `#close`? Don't you confuse it with handling click event? The same issue can easily be reproduced even with single `.profile`

Comment: @zerkms: I see what you mean. You're right. Thanks. Updated my answer to make my point clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified part of you code

```
// return to original start position
$('#close').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     alert('sometimes i get triggered multiple times!');
     activeProfile.css({'left' : initialLeft, 'top' : initialTop});
     e.stopPropagation();
});
```